# How to update a simple DApp(Decentralized) with older dfx version to latest one?

Tags: dapps, dapp-development

I'm trying to deploy my DApp and while the process, I am prompted to update my dfx to above version 0.12.x. But after updating my dfx I'm not able to run my existing DApp locally.

So, I reverted the update to run it in my local environment. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the error? What versions are you trying to use? Without more details we can't help you.